# Visit A Website Behind The Scenes In Adobe Air Application

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, urlrequest

I am needing to find a way in Actionscript 3 for a Adobe Air application to visit a website url (ex. example.com) in the background without Adobe Air opening up a web browser.

After the website has loaded in the background, I would like to get all the URL link that the Adobe Air application may see. For example, maybe when you visit "example.com" it redirects you to "google.com", so I want my application to send me back whatever URL it sees after it loads the page.

I see you can use URLRequest to visit the URL, but I am still having a problem retrieving the new URL after the HTTP request has loaded/completed. Basically, the page that I visit will redirect you to another page, and I need to find out through Actionscript what page it was redirected to by looking at the URL.

Can this be done, and is there any sample code anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a [`StageWebView`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) that you don't actually display (by not setting its `stage` property). You can add listeners for `LOCATION_CHANGING` events to find out what URLs are being loaded after you first used `loadURL()` to load your page.